# Proper way to store boolean in CoreData Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my `Model.xcdatamodeld` I'm setting attribute: `notificationSet as Boolean`. Than in my model I am defining it as a `@NSManaged var notificationSet: NSNumber?`. When i want to save some item using this attribute I'm using it like this:

```
medicine.setValue(false, forKey: "notificationSet")
```

Is this a proper way to store booleans? It will be stored as a false ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your KVC method will work, but it is bad practice. If you change the name of `notificationSet`, you will have to replace strings throughout your project. A typo in the key will compile fine and crash your app at runtime.

Instead, use NSManagedObject subclasses. Xcode can generate those for you automatically.

Also, it normally does not make sense to have a Boolean type as optional. Instead, give it a default value (e.g. "NO") in the model editor. The type is then `NSNumber`, rather than `NSNumber?`.

`false` should work automatically, but if you want to be explicit, you can use

```
medicine.notificationSet = NSNumber(bool: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

The property `notificationSet` contains a boolean value but as the type indicates it's an `NSNumber`. The value you set it to should be of the same type - `NSNumber`.

It implies that you should use the `numberWithBool` method on `NSNumber` to set it. However, Swift is very nice and does it for you. It automatically bridges the boolean to the `NSNumber`. More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_43)

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 8 :

its working by simply doing :
medicine.notificationSet = false